# The INNER JOIN query in Dreamweaver CS6 only picks first record

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, inner-join, dreamweaver

I have two tables that I have created in PHPMYADMIN.  The first table is users and the second table is childcareinfo.  I want to create a query that will pull the childcare the user works at from childcareinfo when the user is logged in.  All pages use MM_UserName and pull the users information throughout the site, however on one page I would like the childcareID (a child column in the users table) to pull the childcare information from the childcareinfo table.  I have written the query

```
SELECT *
FROM childcareinfo INNER JOIN users 
ON childcareinfo.ChildcareID = users.ChildcareID
WHERE UserName = colname
```

However the query will only pull the childcare info from the first entry in the table and not the childcare related to the user logged into the site.  Therefore the childcare is not linked to the user.

Please help, I have tried everything.  Thank you!

I have tried the following code now

```
SELECT *
FROM users INNER JOIN childcareinfo ON childcareinfo.ChildcareID=users.ChildcareID
WHERE ChildcareID = $_SESSION['MM_UserName']
```

However I am being told that there is a syntax error.

The variable connecting the pages is the users UserName from the users table. colname is a variable that Dreamweaver set up using the runtime value of $_SESSION['MM_UserName'] with a -1 default. ChildcareID is the foreign key in the users table connected to the primary key in the childcareinfo table.

Comment: What is colname? Are you sure you don't need "userName" instead?

Comment: The variable connecting the pages is the users UserName from the users table.  colname is a variable that Dreamweaver set up using the runtime value of $_SESSION['MM_UserName'] with a -1 default.  ChildcareID is the foreign key in the users table connected to the primary key in the childcareinfo table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `childcareId` as variable in your page you can use a query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM childcareinfo
INNER JOIN users 
ON childcareinfo.ChildcareID = users.ChildcareID
WHERE ChildcareID = @ChildcareID
```

`@ChildcareID` is the variable passed to this page

Comment: The variable is username that connects each page.  The variable connecting the pages is the users UserName from the users table. colname is a variable that Dreamweaver set up using the runtime value of $_SESSION['MM_UserName'] with a -1 default. ChildcareID is the foreign key in the users table connected to the primary key in the childcareinfo table.